# How to run the PWA page offline on Safari v12

Tags: html, progressive-web-apps

I am using PWA with indexedDB version 2. I have created a demo app and it works good on chrome v76 browser on online and offline as well. Also able to run online but unable to run on offline mode on iPhone 6s Safari v12. When I try to run the page offline then I get below message on browser [image]

Please help how can I run the page offline.